# Unable to correctly import opencsv module for java [package com.opencsv does not exist]

Tags: java, module, opencsv

Here is a simple java code that I wrote where I'd like to parse my csv file using the opencsv module:

```
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class csv_open {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String csvFile = "FebStatement.csv";

    CSVReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
        String[] line;
        while ((line = reader.readNext()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Expense [date= " + line[0] + ", amount= " + line[1] + " , name=" + line[2] + "]");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

In my directory where I have the csv_open.java file, I also have the opencsv-4.1.jar file.
The command that I am using to compile the code on command line is:

```
javac -classpath opencsv-4.1.jar: csv_open.java
```

But that's giving me the following output:
[package com.opencsv does not exist - pls see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LlQ5.png)

I'm refraining from using IntelliJ or Eclipse at the moment or to build this program with Maven or Groovy, etc.
Can I still simply compile and run the code on the command line like above by fixing what's wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue with compiling the com.opencsv.CSVWriter.  I ended up using the below code to compile in the command line and it worked!  I am still learning how to set classpaths and what-not so there may be an easier way but this worked for me.

javac -classpath C:\project\lib\opencsv-4.2.jar -d C:\project\bin\ -sourcepath C:\project\src\ PrepForCPP.java

**Compile code breakdown:**

```
javac = jvm compiler
-classpath = full path of where the jar file is stored
-d = where the various class files for my program are stored
-sourcepath = where all of the different java files for my program are stored
C:\project\src\ = setting the filepath
PrepForCPP.java = file name with main method
```

You may not need the -d and -sourcepath since it looks like you're only using one file.  If I'm understanding the info I'm finding on classpaths correctly, your environmental variable isn't set quite right so the jvm isn't able to find the opencsv-4.2.jar.  I don't think I did either, but including the full file path seems to be a decent work-around for now.

**this does require that the classpath environment variable be set. Otherwise you could include the full filepath of javac.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this and let you know if that worked for me!